# In Julia: The Day of Week defaults to Monday=1, How to set Sunday=1

Tags: date, julia

In the Julia 1.0 documentation for the Dates package it says for the `Dates.dayofweek` function:

"Return the day of the week as an Int64 with 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, etc.."

Example from documentation after adding `using Dates`:

```
julia> using Dates
julia> Dates.dayofweek(Date("2000-01-01"))
6
```

Example for Monday, 9/10/2018:

```
julia> Dates.dayofweek(Date("2018-09-10"))
1
```

I do not see a way to set Sunday=1, Monday=2, etc.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: The accepted answer works great and is illustrated below in contrast to the code above:

```
julia> my_dayofweek(Date("2018-09-10"))
2
```

Comment: Yeah, unexpected by me too, but ISO 8601 says Monday=1.  Wudya gonna do?

Comment: You can access a constant of what integer day of the week it is using `Dates.Sunday` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is hard coded. Therefore I guess that what you can do is define your own function for this:

```
my_dayofweek(x) = dayofweek(x + Day(1))
```